# ng-show, ng-hide not working outside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have tow div's. 
one is **add** and another one is **view**. any one div shows at a time. my add button is placed out of the controller.

```
     <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddClick()" />
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="csrControl" ng-init="viewdiv=true">
     <div id="view" ng-show="viewdiv">
         view
     </div>
     <div id="add" ng-hide="viewdiv">
        Add
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here i have externally called the controller and assign scope variable to false. the variable set as false, but the **div cannot hide and show**. ng-show and ng-hide not working

```
function AddClick() {
       var $scope = 'div[ng-controller="csrControl"]';
       $scope.viewdiv = 'false';
       $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Comment: When you click the button - are you reaching the function? put a break point there

Comment: {{viewdiv}} it shows false on button click. but the show and hide was not working

Comment: In JavaScript, the string `'false'` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: thanks @georgeawg, I have set value as string. Not as truthy. I have set false as truthy, it will perfectly work.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things I changed to get it working:

- Put `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="csrControl"` into the body.
- Move `ng-init="viewdiv=true"` to `$scope.viewdiv = true;`.

and many little things. Check it out.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('csrControl', [
  '$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.viewdiv = true;
    $scope.addClick = function() {
       $scope.viewdiv = false;
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="csrControl">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addClick()" />
 <div>
     <div id="view" ng-show="viewdiv">
         view
     </div>
     <div id="add" ng-hide="viewdiv">
        Add
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my add button comes outside the controller.

Comment: @Prakasam you need to learn more about how angularjs work and how you can take advantage from it.